# Ethernet: What is a jabber timeout

Tags: ethernet

I am writing Ethernet drivers for an STM32 chip. (The reference manual is available [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf).) At various points, the concept of "jabber timeout" appears, and is not explained. A quick Google search didn't reveal much more information.

What is a jabber timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a quick glance at some other datasheets that reference a "jabber timeout".

From the MX98715AEC-C Ethernet chip:

> Transmit Jabber Timeout,
>   indicating the MX98715 has been excessively active. The
>   transmit process is aborted and placed in the stopped state. TDES0<1> is also set

I would guess that the timeout setting stops the transmit process if the chip gets into some state where it wont "shut up" (ie it keeps jabbering on and on)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the info I found in a datasheet. I hope it helps you.

> The MAC maintains a jabber timer to stop the transmission of Ethernet frames if the
>   MAC module transfers more than 2,048 (default) bytes. The timeout is changed to 10,240
>   bytes when the Jumbo frame is enabled.

Comment: Interesting; note that the normal Ethernet max frame is about 1500 bytes, so 2048 should never be seen in normal operation.

Comment: It's probably also work mentioning the particular datasheet to give a bit more context and further reading.